# HAML and Ruby loop and UL not working

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I'm trying to get this simple list working, but the ul is closing and not enclosing the li elements in the loop. Am I missing a simple way to do this?

```ruby
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs.nav-stacked
   - @courses.each do |c|
   %li
    = link_to "add", { :controller => "admin/relateds", :action => "edit", :id => c.id }, :confirm => "Are you sure?"
    = c.coursetitle
```

Comment: Doesn't the LI/etc need to be indented?

Comment: yes - I'd missed that. Fresh eyes. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%li` needs indentation because it is within a `do` block. Even if it is [valid markup](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/#indentation) it will save you debugging time if you opt to use 2 or 4 spaces for indentation for better legibility, as one is very difficult to discern.

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs.nav-stacked
  - @courses.each do |c|
    %li
      = link_to "add", { :controller => "admin/relateds", :action => "edit", :id => c.id }, :confirm => "Are you sure?"
      = c.coursetitle
```

Comment: We all have plenty of times this happens :)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know What would be the syntax to get both ruby blocks into one <li> ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake it's already doing what I wanted. Thanks for you patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

you need to indent the %li and what's supposed to be inside. Currently your loop does nothing.