# Why is my HAML and Ruby loop still not working?

Tags: ruby, haml, block

I have almost the same question as in "[HAML and Ruby loop and UL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192764/haml-and-ruby-loop-and-ul-not-working)", except I think I have proper indentation, and it's still not working.

My HAML code is:

```
%ul.thumbnails
- @images.reverse_each do |image|
  %li.span2
    %div.thumbnail
```

The output is:

```
<ul class="thumbnails"></ul>
<li class="span2">
   <div class="thumbnail"></div>
</li>
```

I think the indentation in the HAML code looks right, doesn't it? I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Indent the loop line (and children nodes) one level more

Comment: Yep, that's it. I'm new to HAML and the documentation was unclear if plaintext ruby needs to be indented or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio's answer helped me. Apparently you have to indent plain ruby as well.

Comment: Yes, you do. Your goal was to nest the Ruby code and subsequent `<li>` tags inside `<ul>`, so everything, including the controlling Ruby logic, has to be indented.